# How do I find out how many objects are included in a MongoDB sparse index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

According to [MongoDB's manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/), in a sparse index only objects including that field are included. I can see the size in bytes of the sparse index, but how do I look up how many objects it includes? I am doing an upgrade on my objects and that number is how many remain to be processed.

Update: My index fields are an Integer and an ObjectId. If they have a fixed size in the index, can I divide its size in bytes by each index size to get an approximate value? Maybe the sparse index size doesn't shrink on the disk as I remove objects with that field...

Comment: Hmm I do not believe there is a method of seeing, a: what is in the tree and b: get object count, I might be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Objects will be included in the sparse index if the respective field is set, even if it is `null`. Hence, you can use [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/) to get the number of elements that have the value set:

```
> db.Foo.count();
185
> db.Foo.find({"SparseField" : {$exists : true} }).count();
174
```

So only 11 documents are not in the sparse index. Alternatively, you can use [`hint`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) to force a query that uses the sparse index and use [`explain`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to retrieve some statistics:

```
> db.Foo.find().hint("sparse_index_name").explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor sparse_index_name",
    "n" : 174,
}
```

**CAVEAT** queries using `explain()` will behave different from queries that don't use explain. Specifically, `db.Foo.find().hint("sparse_index_name").count()` will return 185, not 174.

---

It makes sense to check for correct usage of sparse indexes from time to time:

```
> db.Foo.find({"SparseField" : null }).count();
38
```

Oops. These 38 documents are indexed, probably not intentionally.